# Multivariable Taylor Series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

I would like to show the validity of the multivariable version of Taylor series expansion up to second-order terms (if possible without using one of the explicit forms for the remainder term):

> Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be twice differentiable at
>   $\vec{a} = (a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ and let $\vec{x} = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$.
>   Then
>
> $f(x) = f(a) + \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\partial f(a)}{\partial x_i}
>  (x_i-a_i) + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j=1}^n \frac{\partial^2 f(a)}{\partial
>  x_i \partial x_j} (x_i-a_i)(x_j-a_j) + R(x)$
>
> where $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{R(x)}{||x-a||^2} = 0$.

I let $g(t) = f(a + t(x-a))$. Then I write $g$ in terms of its Taylor Series about $0$, evaluated at $t=1$ to get
        $g(1) = g(0) + g'(0) + \frac{1}{2} g''(0)  + R(1)$.
        Then, using the chain rule
        \begin{align*}
   g(1) &= f(x) \\
   g(0) &= f(a) \\
   g'(0) &= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial f(a)}{\partial x_i} (x_i-a_i) \\
   g''(0) &= \sum_{i,j=1}^n \frac{\partial^2 f(a)}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} (x_i-a_i)(x_j-a_j)
  \end{align*}
Then letting $R(x) = R(1)$, how do I show that $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{R(x)}{||x-a||^2} = 0$ using the fact that
$g(t) = g(0) + g'(0)t + \frac{1}{2} g''(0)t^2  + R(t)$
where $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{R(t)}{t^2} = 0$? Or perhaps another approach is necessary?

Answer (score 1):

$$R(x)=R(1)$$

$$R(1) =\frac{g'''(c)}{3!} = \frac16\sum_{i,j,k=1}^n \frac{\partial^3 f(a+c(x-a))}{\partial x_i \partial x_j \partial x_k} (x_i-a_i)(x_j-a_j)(x_k-a_k)$$

If there is upbound M for all the third derectives, then we get,

$$|R(x)| \lt |\frac M6|~|\sum_{i,j,k=1}^n  (x_i-a_i)(x_j-a_j)(x_k-a_k)|$$

$$\lt |\frac M6|~(\sum_{i}^n  (x_i-a_i)^2)^{\frac 32}$$